# How to process bitmaps from camera preview callback that is constantly called

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, camera, surfaceview

I'm using [onPreviewFrame](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) to get bitmap data from camera preview. I'm processing image (OCR stuff), something like this:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height,null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width,arg1.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height), 80, baos);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray...
        ...
        ...
        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

While activity is running it's ok, it works without lags. But when I press back button there is a lag caused by this image processing.(maybe one-two seconds) It's because its running on the UI Thread. I decided to use HandlerThread but after some time I got OutOfMemory Error caused by bitmap creation in this part of code.

My question is, how to process bitmap data in separated thread that are constantly coming from camera ?

Comment: Why not just start a new thread for every action?

Comment: Try adding bitmap.recycle() to Your code after You are done with it.

Comment: Threads are not ok as they run at the same time so many bitmaps will occupy a lot of memory. Better start an asynctask for every bitmap. They run one after another.